# How to implement knapsack problem with recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, knapsack-problem

So if you arent aware of what the knapsack problem is, it is a way of fitting different weights from a knapsack so that they add up to equal a specified total weight. Here is an example from my book on how to go about solving the problem if the specified total weight was 20.

[image: Link to the image in my book]

If anybody knows how to implement this problem in java using recursion PLEASE help, im so confused. Here is what I started but I'm pretty sure this is wrong and I have no clue where to go now.

```
import java.util.*;

public class n01044854 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please first enter a weight capacity up to a value of 
100, followed by a series of individual weight values with 25 weights being the max.)
");
        String values = input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = values.split(" +");

        int capacity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        int[] weightValues = new int[tokens.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i++)
            weightValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i+1]);
        optimizeWeights(capacity, weightValues, 0);
    }

    public static void optimizeWeights(int target, int[] weights, int currentIndex) {
        if (weights[currentIndex] == target)
            System.out.println("Success! Knapsack optimally filled.");
        else if (weights[currentIndex] < target) {
            int newTarget = target - weights[currentIndex];
            optimizeWeights(newTarget, weights, currentIndex + 1);
        } else if (weights[currentIndex] > target) {
            if (currentIndex < weights.length - 1)
                optimizeWeights(target, weights, currentIndex + 1);
            else
            //confused on what to do 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the example](https://github.com/azee/algo/blob/master/src/main/java/Knapsack.java)

I've implemented it some time ago while I was preparing for technical interviews.